# Why the modifications of a list inside a function do not change the list?

Tags: python, list, pass-by-reference

I am writing a program to remove the duplicated elements from a given sorted list. I wrote function "removeDuplicates" to do some modifications on the list and print the updated list at the end of the function. Since the list is passed by reference, the question is why the changes do not apply on the list outside the function.

```
def removeDuplicates(nums):
    c = 0
    nums = nums + [nums[-1] + 1]  # add a dummy element to the end of the list
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
        if nums[i] != nums[i + 1]:
            nums[c] = nums[i]
            c = c + 1
    nums.pop()
    print(nums)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
    removeDuplicates(nums)
    print(nums)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nums = nums + [nums[-1] + 1]  # add a dummy element to the end of the list
```

Wrong.  You specifically create a *new* list from `nums` and your new element, and then make your local variable `nums` point to that new list.  You then operate nicely on the new list and exit the function without saving the result.

Try

```
nums.append(nums[-1] + 1)  # add a dummy element to the end of the list
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in the line:

```
nums = nums + [nums[-1] + 1]
```

because you are reassigning nums to a new value. Instead, try:

```
nums.append(nums[-1] + 1)
```

This way, you are changing the value of nums *in place*, which means that you're still referring to the same object throughout the function as opposed to creating a new object.

Answer (score 0):

It's because if your second line in `removeDuplicates`:

```
nums = nums + [nums[-1] + 1]  # add a dummy element to the end of the list
```

This makes a new copy of the list parameter `nums` that was passed by reference, and your de-duping operations modify the copy instead of the original list.

Your function also has other issues, without that line I get the output:

```
>>> nums = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
>>> removeDuplicates(nums)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
```

Take a look at this excellent answer for better approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961390/11776945

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, the issue is when you are adding a dummy element. You are creating a new copy of `nums` variable. To avoid this, you can use the `np.append()` method suggested here or simply replace

```
nums = nums + [nums[-1] + 1]
```

with

```
nums += [nums[-1] + 1]
```

This way you will not be creating a new list.